# Real time monitoring system sending real time data to an android device?

Tags: android, real-time

I'm working on a desktop application that monitors an environment (using sensors) and generates real-time data. I need to monitor this data **in real time** using an android device.

And at the same time the android application should be able to send commands to the desktop application.

I'm quite new to smart phone development. Any idea where to start?

Comment: Here http://developer.android.com/index.html
and here
https://www.google.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by learning how to communicate between the android device and PC, which can be achieved via `Bluetooth` or `Wi-Fi`

Android device itself does not have much environmental sensors, so you might need external device, i.e. microcontrollers with such attached sensors (e.g. temperature, humidity, CO2, etc) which you can achieve by using an Arduino or similar microcontrollers.

Alternatively you can just use a ready device such as [Sensordrone: The 6th Sense of Your Smartphone](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/453951341/sensordrone-the-6th-sense-of-your-smartphoneand-be)